# Multithreading not working in Windows Service C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, windows-services

I have a windows service(created using C#), which runs a piece of code every 10 minutes,

- in which I am creating the array of threads and try to execute one single method.
  and each thread supposed to perform their work separately.

But, when I install the service and start the service then after some time it stops automatically.

After checking in Event Viewer, I find the log saying as "The MyService service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s)."

Code:

```
Thread threadarrArray = new Thread[10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   threadarrArray[i] = new Thread(() => Mthd_StartThreadSync());

   threadarrArray[i].Start();
}

private void Mthd_StartThreadSync()
{
   // some code
}
```

Please help.

Comment: You are not by chance using the _Topshelf framework?_

Comment: No, I'm using .Net framework only

Comment: Show us your service's `OnStart` method

Comment: `Timer timer = new Timer();`

`timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);`

`timer.Interval = 600000;`

`timer.Enabled = true;`


`private void OnElapsedTime(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
 // above threading code mentioned in question
}`

Comment: Don't declare `timer` locally inside `OnStart`. Keep the reference in a member field.

Comment: Whilst creating Windows Services (WS) can be fun, be aware that creating a process, WS or thread that spends most of its time sleeping or waiting for a timer to tick over in the order of 10 mins is rather inefficient.  Have you considered using the Windows Task Scheduler? It is a COM API that is easy to use from C#.  _[A simple scripting example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/time-trigger-example--scripting-)_

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'll try doing that, Thank you.

Comment: @MickyD
well there is a piece of code that can run longer sometimes and sometimes it can finish early, so the timer which I'll give for Task Schedular might overlap already running code and start another instance of the code, which I don't want to happen.

Comment: Windows Task Scheduler has many features including _"If the task is already running...do not start a new instance"_.  Your code doesn't seem to be doing that

Comment: @MickyD you think that an out-of-process scheduler, driven by COM, is more efficient than a sleep loop?

Comment: @MartinJames I'm fairly sure that a firing an event `once every 10 minutes` to a single COM event sink in-process or otherwise is considerably _"more efficient"_ than spinning up a Windows process and thread that does nothing but perform a _"sleep loop"_

Comment: The service process already exists, and the timeout thread only needs to be created once.  During the 10 minutes, the thread does nothing and, if required by the OS, could be paged out, as could the other threads.  Upon sleep expiry, it can signal the event/semaphore upon which the other nine threads are waiting and then perform one work unit itself.  It's simple and self-contained, easy to understand, does not need COM and maintains any required state across the sleep interval.  I guess the design choices are personal preference, and I hate COM:)

Comment: Thank You Everyone.

It was just a problem of waiting for one thread to start before starting other thread.

One simple Thread.Sleep() worked and it is now running service without any problem.